# Python regex library can't match even though it should

Tags: python, regex

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re

def grep(filepath, regex):
    regObj = re.compile(regex)
    res = []
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            if regObj.match(line):
                res.append(line)
    return res

print(grep('/opt/conf/streaming.cfg', 'Port='))
```

Supposed to loop through the lines in the file given and match the regex provided, if exists, append to `res` and eventually return `res`.

The content of `/opt/conf/streaming.cfg` contains a line:

```
SocketAcceptPort=8003
```

Still prints `[]`

How come?

Comment: `regObj.match(line)` always return `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the docs for [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=match#re.match) gives us this first sentence:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match

Notice the part about "beginning of string"? You need to use a different re function to match anywhere in the line. For example, further down in the docs for `match` is this note:

> If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use search() instead

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a list of ports, could you not use a string comparison instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re

def grep(filepath, substring):
    res = []
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            if substring in line:
                res.append(line.rsplit("\n")[0])
    return res


print(grep('/opt/conf/streaming.cfg', 'Port='))
```

giving the result:

```
['SocketAcceptPort=8003']
```

Comment: I need to get only the port. I used `match.group(1)`. Can I seperate the port number without regex?

Comment: Sure, replace the line `res.append(line.rsplit("\n")[0])` with `res.append(line.split(substring, 1)[1].rsplit("\n")[0])`, that will give the output `['8003']`